# Publish box in CPT remove 'edit' link

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, links, publish

Hello I have a custom post and in the Publish Box I would like to remove the timestamp edit link.[image]

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why you're wanting to do this? If you are trying to prevent certain users from editing the publication date, there are other ways of doing that.

Comment: hey Shoelaced I just want to remove it, can you do this?

Comment: As far as I know there's no hook to remove it via PHP. You could hide it using javascript or CSS though, I would imagine.

Comment: hey Shoelaced Thank you for your support :)